# Jenkins downstream jobs triggering on Gerrit event

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

in my CI pipeline I have three stages (1, 2 & 3), I use GIT and Gerrit for review support. The process is that stage 1 jobs will be triggered on Gerrit event "patchet created", e.g. code is pushed into a virtual branch and held. If stage 1 finished ok it gives +1 to Gerrit. Once manual review is done the code is merged to master. This merge triggers stage 2 jobs, which finally triggers stage 3.

So, in a downstream Jenkins view it looks like,
stage 1 ; stage 2 -> stage 3

Now I want to use build pipeline plugin for visualization (actually deploy plugin, but it requires build pipeline). This does some analysis of downstream relation to draw a pretty picture of the build and test process. Since stage 1 and stage 2 don't have a downstream relationship it naturally misses these.

Adding downstream relationship breaks my wanted behaviour (I want to have manual review prior to stage 2). Either breaks it by auto triggering on completion of stage 1 or breaks it by requiring manual trigger of stage 2.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? Or event better, a solution?

thanks,
Johan

Answer (score 0):

Just add a manual linkage (second "ticked" on the screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Is this under post-build actions in the job conf? For me it looks different, I have a drop down menu and have tried adding manually trigger next job to no luck.

Comment: Yes, it is, the screenshot is from the plugin page. Can you give the link to yr plugin? We can talk about different ones :D

Comment: Oh, the drop down does not have the build pipeline plugin option but rather only manually Which made me confused and wonder if I was doing it in the right place

Comment: It's probably the same, I recognize the image from setup instructions but it doesn't look the same for me 

Comment: Yep, on my CI it's also a drop down (because there are about 50+ possible post build actions) and while selected it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/Lq5jiLP.png

Comment: Hmm, I can only recall having like 5... I must be missing something. Investigate more tomorrow

Comment: For me it looks exactly the same, then I add my next downstream project then no more options. No tickbox for "build pipeline plugin -> Manually ...". Anyway, if I conf like that then the job is not automatically triggered my Gerrit when review is done, (the project is triggered but the delivery pipeline does not pick it up). I need to manually press the little triangle in the box (in the build pipeline view) to build it.